# Getting response status code as 261

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, http, jax-rs

I am consuming jaxrs service and calling it using `$.ajax()`function of jquery. But randomly in the response getting `xhr.status` code is `261`. Doesn't get any data in the response. Thus my application stucks.
What does this 261 status code mean?

Comment: You should add some more context to your question that will allow us to reproduce it (i.e. JAX-RS implementation, server, some code example)

Answer (score 0):

It's an unregistered status code, so you'll need to ask the people who generate it. In general 2xx means success.

Comment: You mean I have to ask to jaxrs implementers?